# How to find out PCI device by Location Path

Tags: windows, usb, powershell, bluetooth, pci

I want to find out the PCI device in Windows Device Manager.

**I got this location path from:**

```
Device Manager - Bluetooth - Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 
- Properties - Details - Location paths
    
PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(14)
```

The above location path says the Bluetooth is USB device "`#USBROOT(0)#USB(14)`", but that USB device is under "`PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)`".

I tried the following command but not work:

```
Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_LocationPaths -InstanceId "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)"
```

Here is the output:

```
Get-PnpDeviceProperty : No Win32_PnPEntity objects found with property 'DeviceID' equal to 'PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)'.  Verify the value of 
the property and retry.
```

How to find out the real PCI device by searching the "`PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)`" from `powershell` or by using other methods?

Comment: Have you tried switching the view in Device Manager to `Devices by Connection`?

Comment: After switching to the Devices by Connection, I can't find the "Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)" from the tree view. I want to pass the PCI to Hyper-V VM by location path.

Comment: If you first select the device in viewing devices by type, and then switch the view to devices by connection, the tree should expand to your device.

Comment: Thank you. Now I found the PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400): Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft). I can disable the "Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)" but I can't make the "Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)" offline, Hyper-V requires any device to offline to add to VM.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but I stumbled upon this thread while I was researching my own get-pnpdevice Powershell issues. I needed the name of the location path property and found it here, thanks!  And then I noticed your query.... The reason your query didn't work is because you passed it a PCIe location path as an InstanceID.  You already have what you are looking for in that query.
I have Instance IDs and I need to lookup (to verify and compare) PCIe path locations by Instance ID.
So for me I'm doing Discrete Device Assignment on Hyper-v.  So I have some Nvidia A16 GPUs that I need both the PCIe location and the InstanceID, so I can control the device in the Hyper-visor.
So first I get my InstanceIDs:

```
    Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Nvidia A16" | select -Property FriendlyName,InstanceId
```

Then I take my InstanceIDs and get my location paths.  Notice that Instance IDs, unlike Location Paths, start with PCI\VEN_.  (Location paths always start with the PCIRoot.)

```
    Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_LocationPaths -InstanceId "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_25B6&SUBSYS_14A910DE&REV_A1\8&17939770&0&002000100010", "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_25B6&SUBSYS_14A910DE&REV_A1\8&B4161C8&0&006000100010" | select -Property Data
```

In the example I just used 2 of my instance IDs  The data returned will be comma separated and the location paths will be in the same order as the queried  Instance IDs.. so easy to match up, at this point.

```
    {PCIROOT(C9)#PCI(0200)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0200)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0400)#PCI(0000), ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PC10)#ACPI(QR4A)#PCI(0000)...
```

{PCIROOT(16)#PCI(0200)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0200)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0C00)#PCI(0000), ACPI(*SB*)#ACPI(PC01)#ACPI(BR1A)#PCI(0000)...

Just wanted to throw in my 2 cents as your thread helped me, thought I would return the favor and kinda give this thread some finality!
I'm using Windows Server 2022 without a desktop.  So I had to make it work from the CLI.  (It's worth it, shameless plug for Core mode installation of Windows)